# increase the width of an image without modifying its position

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, width

I have an image "oeuf2" whitch is at the center of the screen and I add this code :

```
[UIView transitionWithView:oeuf2 duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void) {


        CGRect newRect = oeuf2.frame;



        newRect.size.width = 300;

        oeuf2.frame = newRect;    





    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {



    }];
```

to increase its width. but when I do that the image move and its center too, so here is my question how can I increase the width of "oeuf2" without modifying its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
CGPoint center = oeuf2.center;
//Change the frame here
oeuf2.center = center;
```

Hope this helps.